# Tomcat windows service unable to access network drive

Tags: java, tomcat, windows-services, network-security

I have two windows domains A and B.

I have two servers: `nasB` on domain B, and `webserverA` on domain A.

I have two users: `userB` on domain B and access to `nasB` and `userA` on domain A with access to `webserverA`

I am running tomcat as a service on `webserverA` and it has the logon as property set to `userA`.

I have `\\nasB\myFiles$\` mapped on `webserverA` using `userB` credentials.  The mapping is only to allow the JVM access.  I always access the drive using UNC in the code.  I also have credentials in the manage network passwords.  Both methods work when running any java app directly but not as a service :(

If I run tomcat as a service it throws a filenotfound except when trying to access `\\nasB\myFiles$\somefile.txt`.  If I run tomcat using the startup.bat it can access the file fine.

I cannot run tomcat service using `userB` as he does not have access to `webserverA`.  How do I let my tomcat service use the `userB` credentials when accessing `nasB`?

Comment: "If I run tomcat using the startup.bat it can access the file fine" - which user are you logged in as when you do that?

Comment: `userA`.  But as I noted he has `nasB` mapped using `userB` credentials.  Also, I am using UNC in all locations not the map drive letter.

Answer (score 3):

Don't try using mapped drives.

Given the fact users' configuration and mapped drives are available only if the user logins using interactive login, you won't be able to use such resources. Try with UNC paths and, if that doesn't work due to user restrictions, get a hand over jcifs library, it is quite handy in those cases because it allows you to authenticate when accesing the resource with the UNC path, so it reduces uncertainty about ability to read folders and files in network drives (also, configuring tomcat service to be ran as an administrative user, giving credentials that shouldn't expire,...).

I' ve faced this myself and this is just my personal view.

Comment: I am using UNC in all locations.  will JCIFS let me access the drive with the UNC from fileinputstream?  I toss the file location into third party libraries that use fileinputstream to open the files.

Comment: JCIFS deals with authentication and creates an appropiate instance if successful. AFAIk it should allow you to read files within as the auth was right already.

Answer (score 0):

Create Windows user with username/password  identical on both Windows servers.
Example userA/passA
Then run Tomcat Windows service with that user.